# Client server QT 5.14 | Клиент не может достучаться до сервера

Tags: c++, qt, клиент-сервер

Приступил к изучению фреймворка Qt. Дошел до изучения Клиент серверных приложений. Как для примера нашел скрипт на [клиент](https://github.com/forstudentgit/json_client_1), и [сервер](https://github.com/forstudentgit/json_server_1). Затем скомпилировал, запустил. Сервер не слышит клиента совсем. Я удалил антивирусник, отключил брандмауэр. Ничего не помогает. Начал выводить статус сокетов, если тыкать на кнопку подключение много раз - вылезает `QAbstractSocket::connectToHost() called when already looking up or connecting/connected to "127.0.0.1" QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState`

Попробовал подключиться через putty, не подключается. Посоветуйте, что может быть не так? в каком месте еще посмотреть настройки компа?

Comment: без кода вам никто ничего по делу не скажет

Comment: Попробуйте отловить пакеты программой Wireshark или каким-либо другим сниффером. Так вы поймёте, на чьей стороне проблема: клиента или сервера.

Comment: Выложите код программы, чтобы вам смогли помочь.